# Error in formula field,

Tags: formula-field

I have been trying for some time to add some type of an alert to our Approval page. So far everything that I've tried isn't possible. The person who requested the modification changed the request a little. Now, we can put a checkbox in the Detail section at the top of the page. It was suggested to me previously to possibly try to use a formula field and an image.

I have created an image and put that in Static Resources. How it is **supposed to** work is if the checkbox is checked, the formula field should display the image that I created. The problem I have now is the formula field code I came up with gets a

> **Error: Syntax error. Extra ','** error.

I've tried many changes to the code, but I manage to get different errors. Can anyone see what is wrong here?  The checkbox is "Conditional_Approval__c" and the image is "TmpApprWarn".  Here's the code:

```
IF (Conditional_Approval__c),   
    IMAGE("/resource/TmpApprWarn", 
    "This Opportunity has a Conditional Approval!") , "")
```

I REALLY appreciate any help!! This "project" has been driving me crazy and I hope this will actually work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for IF is IF (boolean condition, result if true, result if false)

So, the braces should close just at the end, rather than after Conditional_Approval__c (assuming Conditional_Approval__c is boolean)

```
IF (Conditional_Approval__c, 
IMAGE("/resource/TmpApprWarn", "This Opportunity has a Conditional Approval!"), 
"")
```

Comment: Well I'll be...it works and actually functions on the page (something else has got to go wrong now)!! Thank you very much @techtrekker for the help...it is much appreciated!!!  Kurt